# linq problem with distinct function

Tags: linq

I am trying to bind distinct records to a dropdownlist. After I added distinct function of the linq query, it said "DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Source'. " I can guarantee that that column name is 'Source'. Is that name lost when doing distinct search?

> My backend code:

```
public IQueryable<string> GetAllSource()
        {
            PromotionDataContext dc = new PromotionDataContext(_connString);
            var query = (from p in dc.Promotions
                         select p.Source).Distinct();
            return query;
        }
```

> Frontend code:

```
PromotionDAL dal = new PromotionDAL();
        ddl_Source.DataSource = dal.GetAllSource();
        ddl_Source.DataTextField = "Source";
        ddl_Source.DataValueField = "Source";
        ddl_Source.DataBind();
```

Any one has a solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you thing an IQueryable< **String** > has a `Source` property?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to bind object not string.

Comment: But your query returns a sequence of strings - look at the method declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already selecting `Source` in the LINQ query, which is how the result is an `IQueryable<string>`. You're then *also* specifying `Source` as the property to find *in each string* in the databinding. Just take out the statements changing the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties in databinding.

Alterantively you could remove the projection to `p.Source` from your query and return an `IQueryable<Promotion>` - but then you would get distinct *promotions* rather than distinct *sources*.

One other quick note - using query syntax isn't really helping you in your `GetAllSources` query. I'd just write this as:

```
public IQueryable<string> GetAllSource()
{
    PromotionDataContext dc = new PromotionDataContext(_connString);
    return dc.Promotions
             .Select(p => p.Source)
             .Distinct();
}
```

Query expressions are great for complicated queries, but when you've just got a single select or a where clause and a trivial projection, using the dot notation is simpler IMO.

Comment: @Steven: In which way? I've given you various different suggestions - first and foremost, to just drop the calls which set the DataTextField and DataValueField properties. (You could possibly set them to "" if you wanted.)

Comment: It works when I set DataTextField and DataValueField to "". but I don't understand what you mean on "using the dot notation".

Comment: @Steven: Using the Select extension method directly instead of writing a query expression. It's just a different way of using LINQ - I prefer it for simple queries like yours.

Comment: Could you write in details? I just start to use Linq. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Steven: I *have* given details - I've given the translation of your current method into dot notation instead of a query expression.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to bind strings, not Promotion objects... and strings do not have Source property/field

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns a set of strings, not a set of objects with properties.

If you really want to bind to a property name, you need a set of objects with properties (eg, by writing `select new { Source = Source }`)

Comment: Yea, I understand. But I need to distinct Source in the query. Do you know how to return objects set with distinct Source value? I'm new on Linq.

Comment: If you want objects (not just strings), you'll need to group by `Source` and select `group.First()` or something.